# Prove that if $a+b+c = 1$ then $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \leq 3+ 2\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove that if $a+b+c = 1$ then $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \leq 3+ 2\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$

What I've done so far is to note that

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = \frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}
\end{align}
$$

And by AM-GM along with the fact that $a+b+c = 1$ we have that

$$
\begin{align}
ab+bc+ca \leq a^2+b^2+c^2 &= (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)\\ 
&= a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b
\end{align}
$$

And once again using AM-GM we have that $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \leq a^3+b^3+c^3$ so using this we have that:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \leq 2\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}+\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc}
\end{align}
$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here because the only thing I can think of is that by the same AM-GM argument $a^2c+b^2a+c^2b \leq a^3+b^3+c^3$ but this only leads me to:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \leq 3\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}
\end{align}
$$

But that's not what I'm asked to prove so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a,b,c&gt;0$ and $a+b+c=1$, then prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\le 3+2\cdot\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673167/if-a-b-c0-and-abc-1-then-prove-that-frac1a-frac1b-frac1c) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%7D%5Cleq%203%2B2%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%7D%7Babc%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%3D1%24&p=1). Note that, although the problem statement doesn't explicitly state ...

Comment: (cont.) that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all positive, the use of the AM-GM inequality in several places indicates at least the product $abc$ is. Also note that the inequality is not necessarily true if you allow any one of the values to be negative. This is asked about, and then stated in Post #$16$ (although Post #$15$ says they don't), of the AoPS thread [Inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1427647p8044040). Also, the Approach0 search had additional multiple AoPS thread results, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2317704p18472258), [restrictive inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2072298p14846245), [Muirhead's Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1872215p12705331), [Inequalities Problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2052104p14587233), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Multiplying throughout by $abc$ and homogenising, we need to equivalently prove:

$$(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c) \leqslant 3abc+2(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$
$$\iff (a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)+(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)\leqslant 2(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$

Which is true, as by Rearrangement Inequality, $a^3+b^3+c^3\geqslant a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3\geqslant ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$.

Comment: And the downvote was for?